# Better_Errors Gem: "exception_extension:rb:6: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, better-errors-gem

I imported my Ruby on Rails project from Cloud9 to my local desktop environment (OS X Yosemite) in order to work on the site without a constant internet connection. rbenv installed the Ruby version, bundler installed the gems + dependencies just fine, and I got the server running with no hassle.

However, upon trying to install the "better_errors" gem just now alongside "binding_of_caller" in order to be able to better recognize and diagnose issues in my project, when I run 'rails s' I get the following error message:

```
     /Users/useraccount/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/better_errors-2.1.1/lib/better_errors/exception_extension.rb:6: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Prior to the attempted installation of "better_errors", the server would start and operate without hassle. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Did you try to run the server without `better_errors`? *Also, I guess this has nothing to do but is `useraccount` your system username?`

Comment: Yes, the server runs without any errors when I remove `better_errors` from the Gemfile. And yeah my OSX username is `useraccount`, the system's name itself is `notebookcomputer` (I noticed everyone's Macbook name gets shared on my school's WiFi with the other systems so I chose something generic)

Comment: you have `binding_of_caller` installed as well correct?

Comment: Yes, i had both binding_of_caller and better_errors installed. When i removed them from the Gemfile the server ran just fine, so I assume one or both of them is causing the issue

Comment: @hworth Try `better_errors` alone, then also try `binding_of_caller` alone and then try a couple of previous versions for whichever doesn't work. That way you'll be able to open an issue at the gem's github page with all the details (rails, ruby and gem's versions as well as the rest of your gemfile).

Comment: @sebkomianos how can I downgrade the `better_errors` gem in order to try different versions? So far even just putting `better_errors` back in the gemfile under group :development without `binding_of_caller` makes the Rails server fail to start (with `better_errors` by itself, I don't see an error message, but the Terminal just takes my `rails s` command and then hangs with a blank, blinking cursor)

Comment: @hworth The syntax is `gem "the_gem", "X.Y.Z"`, where "X.Y.Z" is the version you want. The latest version is 2.1.1 (https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors/releases) so I'd try 2.1.0, 2.0.0 and 1.9

Comment: @sebkomianos I ended up having to go back to version `1.1.0` in order for the Rails server to actually start up with `better_errors` installed. However, now the webpages still won't load in the browser, and I just see processes in the Terminal hang after a couple of "GET" requests; these requests always seem to be related to `assets/jquery.image-select` or `assets/chosen.jquery`

Comment: @hworth Unfortunately I can't help anymore - my experience is limited. I think your best shot is to open an issue on the gihtub page (https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors/issues/new) explaining your problem, listing your gems and mentioning that `1.1.0` kinda works. **Don't forget to let them know about your `rails` and `ruby` versions too!**